# USB port does not work neither on windows windows nor linux

Tags: linux, windows-10, usb, hp-pavilion

I have a HP laptop and the two usb port on the left stopped working. They are not giving any power and I can't see them in the device manager on Windows. I tried on Linux and they are not working either. I opened my laptop and found that the two usb port are on the same card. I checked every connection and they are all good. It's been a month since they don't work and I have no idea where it can come from. I have a jack port on the same and it is working.

Comment: The chip that controls them could be dead. How old is the laptop?

Comment: It's only a year and a half old. I'm afraid that it would be a hardware issue...

Comment: If still under warranty, use it.

Comment: The warranty is over. Do you know where I can buy spare parts ?

Comment: Check Ebay or others for same machine with broken screen/keyboard/HDD and swap motherboards (you will have to transfer the windows licence).

Comment: I second "probably the hardware is dead", but you can try `lsusb -t` under Linux, see how many ports you get and plug stuff in the remaining ports to identify them to get an idea what is broken: The root hub, an intermediate hub, or wiring for the ports.

Comment: I will try to debug the problem on linux. Hopefully I don't have to change the whole motherboard because the usb ports are on a separate card.